# How to generate Word document(doc,docx) in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-word

How to generate Word document(doc,docx) in ASP.NET?

Comment: Joel offers some tips for that here: [Why are the Microsoft Office file formats so complicated? (And some workarounds)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create OpenXML documents using the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en). Note that this only applies to `.docx`, not `.doc` binary files from earlier versions of Word.

Documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

Comment: And you can augment that with docx4j.NET for stuff which isn't easy out of the box with the SDK, such as mail merge, XHTML import, PDF export.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WordML to create Word 2003 docx: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=xml&seqNum=176

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)

Comment: but if do this with Aspose.Words I must to have license

Comment: too expensive for simple things