# MVC 3 create Microsoft Word report Document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ms-word

I have a project where I need to  create a Word document report based on some items which custumer can choose on MVC 3 (Razor) website.

Is it possible in any way? The only solutions I can find is report in Excel.

Do I need to create Word Templates?

Comment: Do you mean a **report**? You are looking for a way to generate a _Word Document_ report from your MVC3 application?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+word+document and this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475471/how-to-generate-word-documentdoc-docx-in-asp-net

Comment: Yes i mean a report based on MVC 3 app data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use the: [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx)

there are many advantages in doing this like no need to instantiate Word on the web server, probably not even need to have it installed...

Comment: Yes. Open XML SdK is the solution (until you can/want to use Word OLE Automation on the server). If you go with the Open XML, just take a look at OpenXML Powertools (it's an assembly with several goodies for working with XML docs).