# Generate a business letter for 100+ leads using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

We need to print Business Letter for a given list with mail merge facilities.

My client is not willing to spend $$ on a paid ASP.NET control to make PDF. So I opted in for WKHTMLtoPDF and it works fine for us until one day the client tried to get a PDF of 100+ leads, resulting in complete failure of PDF generation. It works just fine with a 10-20 page PDF, but not for 100.

Are there any tips & tricks to improve performance? We are using Cloud-hosted IIS 7 with ASP.NET 4 if that matters.

Answer (score 5):

**PDFSharp** library is really a nice one!

I have used it for quite a while now, and I find it flexible enough to fulfill your needs.

However there are [some aspects](http://kolezhuk.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/pdf-report-generation-in-asp-net/#more-209) of using it as a "standalone library" - e.g creating tables is a headache and there aren't much text formatting options. It is much better to mix it together with [MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) (an extension library for PDFSharp).

Comment: Well, latest version of wkhtmltopdf is much improved and is best as it take a simple HTML and do the job. PDFSharp is good, but is complicated when compare to wkhtmltopdf. But thanks for your link it looks good.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a really free (as in "free of worries") library, choose iTextPDF versions prior to version 4.1.7, as they state [in the ByteScout blog](http://blog.bytescout.com/2011/04/net-bear-do-you-know-any-free-pdf.html).

From the ByteScout blog:

> iTextSharp 4.1.6 DLL only: [itextsharp-4.1.6-dll.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/itextsharp-4.1.6/itextsharp-4.1.6.zip/download)
>   iTextSharp 4.1.6 Source Code (C#): [itextsharp-4.1.6.zip](http://bytescout.com/files/other/itextsharp-4.1.6.zip)

I'm not sure I understand your problem but couldn't you [generate docx documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475471/how-to-generate-word-documentdoc-docx-in-asp-net) and get the same results?

Answer (score 3):

For all, I use http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ to create HTML to PDF, my ASP.NET code generate the HtML file then I create HTML to PDF and it is done, much easier than using itextpdf's Table and td structure to get things in better space. I found it easy and **fast once you get your stuff aligned properly**.

library has improved since original question asked and it performs better now.

Comment: the OP indicated that this library is not good for the size of files his client is trying to generate.

Comment: Also it does not exist anymore

Comment: I recently use puppeteer from nodejs, and it produce some good results as well.

Answer (score 2):

here is good tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20640/Creating-PDF-Documents-in-ASP-NET

Comment: itextSharp is paid thing for commercial usage, and as I said client is not ready to pay their very high price.

Comment: iTextSharp is also available for free under the AGPL, with the only condition that your code will be under AGPL too.