# Create Word document on server and offer Client as Download

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Hi iam creating a Word document like:

```
    Dim oApp As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")


    oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add


    Dim rng As Word.Range = oDoc.Range(0, 0)
    rng.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    rng.Font.Size = 16


    .......
    ...............



    oApp.Visible = True

    oDoc = Nothing
    oApp = Nothing
```

This works perfect on my local machine. But if i put my Code on Webserver it of course does not work.

My Question is: What i have to do, that the Word document gets created on the server and offer the created document to the client as Download.

Can someone help me with that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think they way you are currently doing this requires Microsoft Word (Or at least the Interop components) to be present on the server to allow this.

Perhaps a better approach would be to create a PDF on the fly and offer that to the client

alternatively perhaps [this](http://www.cosninix.com/wp/2010/04/generating-microsoft-office-documents-word-excel-on-your-webserver-using-php/) approach would work or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb735940%28v=office.12%29.aspx)?

EDIT:

Also please see [how-to-generate-word-documentdoc-docx-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475471/how-to-generate-word-documentdoc-docx-in-asp-net)

EDIT:

This code snippet will allow you to stream the file down to the client

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Create Document
            using (<declare document>))
            {
               //create your document here


                // Stream it down to the browser

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=HelloWorld.docx");
            mem.Position = 0;
            mem.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I have Microsoft word on my Webserver. It should be a Word document. Do you have a example on how to do that with vb.net?

Comment: How are you currently trying to stream the content down to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this...

I have managed to get Word running on a server (Apache).  You must run Apache under a user account that can run Word.  Also if you use Office 32-bit you must run Apache 32-bit.  Only one instance of Word runs at one time. However, Word can have multiple documents open at the same time.  I developed an addin that I put in Word's startup directory so it is available for each document.  In the AutoExec macro I trigger the code that reads a job queue and generates the document.  All this is run from the web using AJAX and PHP.